# Flatten Hierarchy in Power BI Direct Query

Tags: powerbi, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, powerbi-embedded

I need to flatten an hierarchy in POWER BI which. Cannot use Path / Path Item functions, neither can I go for mixed mode of Import + Direct Query.

Sample Data :

### Level | Product ID | Product Name   | Parent ID

3     | P1        | Vit C         | P2
2     | P2        | Serum         | P3
1     | P3        | Cosmetics     | NULL
2     | P4        | Moisturiser   | P3
3     | P5        | Aloe          | P4

I need a result as

### Level 1 | Level 2      | Level 3

Cosmetics| Serum       | Vit C
Cosmetics| Moisturiser | Aloe

and so on.....